# Add Image in background using default.css in eclipse e4

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am creating a Eclipse e4 RCP Application. I want to add a image at the background. I have tried adding property in plugin.xml:

```
<property
        name="applicationCSSResources"
        value="platform:/plugin/rcptutorial/image/image.jpg">
```

Also, I created a new folder  "Images" and added "image.jpg in it. I also added the line in default.css:

```
Shell {  background-image: url('./image.jpg');}
```

But nothing happens when I run it. I can apply background-color but unable to add image.

Please help.

My Plugin.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>

<plugin>  

<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="org.rcptutorial.rcp"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     <property
           name="lifeCycleURI"
           value="bundleclass://rcptutorial/org.rcptutorial.rcp.E4LifeCycle">
     </property>
     <property
           name="applicationCSS"
           value="platform:/plugin/rcptutorial/css/default.css">
     </property>
     <property
        name="applicationCSSResources"
        value="platform:/plugin/rcptutorial/images/">
    </property>



  </product>


</extension>

</plugin>
```

My default.css is as follows:

```
Shell {  background-image: url('./images/image.jpg');}
```

I have an "images" folder that contains the image "image.jpg". The folder is located inside my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`applicationCSSResources` must specify a folder which contains the images:

```
<property
      name="applicationCSSResources"
      value="platform:/plugin/rcptutorial/image/">
</property>
```

(the ending '/' must be present).

The URL in the CSS should just be:

```
url('./image.jpg')
```

Comment: i added this property. Also, in my css, I changed the background-image url to:

Shell {  background-image: url('./images/image.jpg');} 
but nothing happened. I still am unable to load image at background

Comment: Show us your complete plugin.xml

Comment: I have edited the question. I have added my complete plugin.xml and my default.css file

Comment: Your url should just be './image.jpg' assuming it is in the images directory.

Comment: If you are running this from an exported product make sure the css and images directories are listed in the build.properties.

Comment: `(the ending '/' must be present).` This was my issue. Thanks @greg-449.